# how can I get file content backwards

Tags: unix

I need to print a file, but from the last line to the first.
I think I can append a number to the beginning of each line, sort descending, and then remove the line numbers, but there's probably some more elegant way to do that. is there?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tac` command 
(tac- cat spelled backwards...)